# How do you separate links in a bootstrap navbar so there is white space between them?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this is a novice question, I just started with Bootstrap. I am trying to build a navbar for my website, and the text links are pushed together so there is no space between them. So instead of this:

**Cars for Sale  Sell a Car  Terms and Conditions**

I have this:

**Cars for SaleSell a CarTerms and Conditions**

I have tried reorganizing the navbar with a list, but that only seems to make it worse, as it misaligned the text and pushed it to the top of the div.

Here's what I have for code:

```
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:indigo">
        <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://localhost:44353/index.html" style="color:white">Cars.com</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Cars for Sale</a>
                    <a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Sell a Car</a>
                    <a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Terms and Conditions</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I would like to just have some space in between the text links so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding-left or padding-right css properties as well.
A few class names for bootstrap nav were missing, here you go.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:indigo;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"  href="https://localhost:44353/index.html" style="color:white;">Cars.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">  <a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Cars for Sale</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Sell a Car</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item active" href="#" style="color:white">Terms and Conditions</a></li> 
        
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```